# Resizable circle overlay in Android GoogleMap

Tags: android

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34542816/resizable-circle-overlay-in-android
Resizable circle overlay in Android GoogleMap
I need exact output like this.

Answer (score 0):

Change it radius.

```
mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
            .center(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()))
            .radius(100)
            .strokeColor(Color.RED)
            .fillColor(Color.BLUE));
```

Comment: I would like resize circle in App Running time.

Comment: need for move and resize map circles using gestures.

Comment: You can do this with the new latitude and longitude values obtained using the LocationListener.